# Using apiaxle with redis instance that requires auth

Tags: redis, apiaxle

We have a redis instance setup with ObjectRocket which provides us with a host, port, and auth key.  I can connect fine with the redis-cli to the instance but I can not figure out how to configure apiaxle-proxy to use the auth key.  I have the config json file setup with the host and port but have tried an auth key and a password key in the config file and have not been able to get it to work.

Does apiaxle support connecting to a redis instance that requires auth?

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, apiaxle actually did not have this support.  I forked and submitted a pull request for this and now it does support authenticated redis stores.